# How to query Oracle db to display table/view?

Tags: database, view, oracle, datatable

Using SharePoint 2010, how can you connect to Oracle db to query a view and display the table in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure a custom BDC model, external content type, and then an external list. There is a really good article at [C# Corner on the topic](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/integrating-oracle-into-sharepoint-2010-using-business-data-connectivity-model/).

Here are the steps at a high level:

1. Using VisualStudio create new Project of type SharePoint 2010 > Business Data Connectivity Model.
2. Modify the default Entity from the BDC Model to fit your view.
3. Build the Read Operations.
4. Configure Business Data Connectivity access rights in Central Admin.
5. Build/Deploy the solution
6. Creating the External List.

Here are two MSDN articles on the topic as well.

[How to: Connect to an Oracle Database Using Business Connectivity Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464424%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Sample BDC Model: Connecting to an Oracle Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512794%28v=office.14%29.aspx)